# FOS Rest Bundle - How to make all responses uniform(my custom format)?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I am learning FOS Rest Bundle at the moment. I have basic setup, set JSON for the response format etc. However I would like to always return my custom format, something like this:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "atr1": "value1",
        "atr2": "value2"
    },
    "message": "",
    "errors": []
}
```

As I see it, I should make custom serializer/normalizer but don't understand it quite. Where should I put those classes and how to register those in FOSRestController?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the Framework [native serializer documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html), you can make some custom format from your [JSON] Response. An other method is to use [JMS Serializer Bundle](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer).

This is a way do achieve this :

1. Make [entities model](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html),
2. Develop your own [API Controller with FOS Rest Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html),
3. Configure the way [entities can be rendered](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations),
4. Make a custom [view layer](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html) with Twig,
5. Play with the just created API with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for exemple...

Hope this help you...

Comment: Why do I need Twig when output will be JSON response?